# Generating labels in macro preprocessing in C

Tags: c, macros

How to write a macro which calls goto END_ label?

For ex:

```
#define MY_MACRO() \
//How to define goto END_##function_name label??

my_function()
{
    MY_MACRO();

END_my_function:
   return;
}
```

The MY_MACRO should simply replace with the line

```
goto END_my_function;
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it can be done. Even though some compilers define `__FUNCTION__` or `__func__`, these are not expanded in macros.

However, note that you don't need a separate label for each function: you can use `END` for all functions and simply write `goto END`.

Comment: `__func__` is C99, and this is a string, not an identifier.

Comment: Yeah! I ended up doing that! :)

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor does not know what function it is in. But you can get close -- you'll have to pass the function name to this macro

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GOTO_END(f) goto f ## _end

void foo(void)
{
   printf("At the beginning.\n");

   GOTO_END(foo);

   printf("You shouldn't see this.\n");

  foo_end:
   printf("At the end.\n");
   return;
}

int main()
{
   foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [token concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation).

```
#define MY_MACRO( function_name ) END_ ## function_name
```

Comment: The point seems to be to avoid giving `function_name` explicitly.